# Windows gnu make with -j option behaves strangely, not taking a number, but hanging on no number

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using gnu make to build a top level with many sub-makefiles, when i do make with no -j at all, it builds serially, i can see that..  When I build with make -j 6  it also builds serially (no faster). but if i use make -j by itself, it flys through the subtargets  (parallel building all files) until it hits a subtarget with a ton of files.. at some point during this, it hangs forever..  I dont really want to try to figure out why it hangs forever because i really want -j 6 and i theorize there would be no hanging if i didnt do infinite jobs..

My question is, is there some trick to get -j 6 to work ?  i am using sh.exe and gnu make.exe -h shows version 3.80.  i read -j doesnt work in windows, but i think it didnt at one time, but it  does *now* (plus i see the infinite jobs flying so its doing something)..

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "-j [jobs], ... If the -j option is given without an argument, make will not limit the number of jobs that can run simultaneously." -- GNU make man page

Comment: Yes, I read that and I understand that is most likely related to why it hangs on too many files/jobs..  my problem, though, is that when i give a number like -j 6, it does one job, it either does single job or infinite jobs, nothing  in between is working,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the version of GNU make you have, on Windows the `-j` option with no argument will cause an infinite number of potential parallel jobs to run.  But the `-j N` option with an argument will behave the same as no `-j` at all (serially).  In other words, the behavior you're seeing is exactly as expected... on Windows.

The hard part is *not* how to run jobs in parallel.  The hard part is tracking how many parallel jobs are running, across recursive invocations of `make`.  On Linux, MacOS, and other POSIX-like systems, different instances of GNU make communicate with each other to ensure that no more than N jobs are running across all the recursive instances.  On Windows that support is not present in the version of GNU make you're using.

However, support for this feature for Windows was added in the latest version of GNU make, version 4.0.  Unfortunately some other issues have popped up that weren't discovered in testing (GNU make could really use a lot more Windows-based testers so if you have the ability, I urge you to subscribe to the bug-make@gnu.org and/or make-w32@gnu.org mailing lists to be notified when release candidates are available).  There are good builds of GNU make 4.0 out there which have patches applied to get them working on Windows.  Or you can wait for the next version which will fix those issues (and hopefully not create new ones).

Comment: Thank you very much, you have explained it! i will search for gnu make 4.0 and i will try it..

Comment: If this answers your question please mark it as answered (by clicking the check mark next to the answer) so others know that it is answered.

Comment: Okay I built make 4.0 and its doing exactly what I want..  seems to work just fine for me..